# PHPで型の継承、データ型の継承について混乱しています。

Tags: php

とある学習サイトで以下のような説明がありました。

> Post型の変数を受け取る関数を作って、データ型が継承されることを説明していきます。
>
> 型の継承 型を継承するメリット

クラスを継承すると親クラスのプロパティやメソッドが子クラスに継承されるというのは理解できています。

”データ型が継承される”というのはここでは下記の2か所を指しているのでしょうか？
`%s` と `%s by %s` で「文字列を出力する」とフォーマットが指定されています。

```
public function show(){
    printf('%s',$this->text);
}
```

と

```
public function show(){
    printf('%s by %s', $this->text, $this->sponsor);
}
```

要するにこのサイトのこの項目ではプロパティやメソッドだけでなく付随するデータ型(
文字列型、整数型、浮動小数点数型、論理型、配列型、オブジェクト型、リソース型、NULL)
も継承されるということなのでしょうか？

初歩的な質問かと思いますが「Post型の変数を受け取る関数を作って、データ型が継承されることを説明していきます。」という文面に対して混乱しています。ウェブサイトや教材を眺めてもクラスの継承の際に”データ型”も継承されるというという点を見つけることが出来ませんでした。
初学者です。もし解釈が間違っているのならばご指摘願います。

---

#### ソースコード

```
<?php

    class Post{
    
    protected $text;
    
    public function __construct($text){
      $this->text = $text;
    }
     public function show(){
    
      printf('%s',$this->text);
    }
    }
    //↑------classPost------↑
    
    //↓------classSponsoredPost------↓
    
    class SponsoredPost extends Post{
      
      private $sponsor;
    
      public function __construct($text, $sponsor){
        parent::__construct($text);
        $this->sponsor = $sponsor;
      }
      
    
      public function show(){
        printf('%s by %s', $this->text, $this->sponsor);
      }
    }
    //↑------classSponsoredPost------↑
    $posts = [];
    $posts[0] = new Post('hello');
    $posts[1] = new Post('hello again');
    $posts[2] = new SponsoredPost('iPhone','Apple');
    
    function processPost(Post $post){
      $post->show();
    }

// 型の継承がされているでSponsoredPost型のインスタンスも
// Post型として扱うことができうまくいく

    foreach($posts as $post){
      processPost($post);
      echo "<br>";
```

#### 表示結果

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 可能であれば参照したサイトの URL も質問中に含めてみてください。

Comment: すみません。ドットインストールという有料のオンライン学習プログラムです習内容は観れないはずですが。学習項目の一覧は見れると思います。これが判断材料になればと思っているのですが…　ソースは書き起こしている通りです。https://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_php_objects

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/344079